# как создать на Котлине List с таким же содержимым, как уже существующий (заменить его новым?)

Tags: kotlin, list

Господа кто знает как создать на Котлине List с таким же содержимым, как уже существующий (заменить его новым?)
например на java я делал так:

```
mList = new ArrayList(mList); // create a new list with same contents
```

Answer (score 0):

получилось так:
mList = ArrayList(mList)